# Bing Map widget coordinates changed when using up and down arrow keys

Tags: scrollbar, coordinates, bing-maps

In my page I used Bing Map functionality to show the list of addresses in map. But when I scroll up or down using keyboard arrows, it only scrolls the map and the page scroll is not working. Before scroll the coordinates is shown in that page

[image]

**After scroll**

[image]

When scroll on that page,the map coordinates changed instead of page scroll. How can this issue be fixed.

Anyone can help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your code (myMap is the instance of your map)

```
  Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(myMap, 'keydown', function(e){
    e.handled = true;
  });
```